# Swift 2 Core Location not working

Tags: ios, core-location, swift2, xcode7

I am trying to set up CoreLocation using Swift 2 (Xcode 7 beta, iOS 9), but the "didUpdateLocations" function is never being called. I would really appreciate any help I could get. Here is my code:

```
//
//  ZmanimController.swift
//  YidKit
//
//  Created by Dani Smith on 7/12/15.
//  Copyright © 2015 Daniel Smith. All rights reserved.
//

import Foundation
import CoreLocation

class ZmanimController: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate
{
//Variables*****************************************
let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
var lat = 0.0
var long = 0.0
var alt = 0.0
var kosherCocoaLocation: KCGeoLocation = KCGeoLocation()
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()

//The zmanim calendar


override init()
{
    super.init()
    self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

    //Calendars
    let zmanimCalendar: KCComplexZmanimCalendar = KCComplexZmanimCalendar(location: kosherCocoaLocation)
    let astronomicalCalendar: KCAstronomicalCalendar = KCAstronomicalCalendar(location: kosherCocoaLocation)
    astronomicalCalendar.workingDate = NSDate()

    //Date formatter stuff
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = .MediumStyle
    dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone()

    print(dateFormatter.stringFromDate(zmanimCalendar.alos72()))

}


//loacation stuff**************************
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])
{
    var latestLocation: AnyObject = locations[locations.count - 1]
    let locationArray = locations as NSArray
    let locationObj = locationArray.lastObject as! CLLocation
    let coord = locationObj.coordinate

    var latitude = String(format: "%.4f",
        coord.latitude)
    var longitude = String(format: "%.4f",
        coord.longitude)
    var horizontalAccuracy = String(format: "%.4f",
        latestLocation.horizontalAccuracy)
    var altitude = String(format: "%.4f",
        latestLocation.altitude)
    var verticalAccuracy = String(format: "%.4f",
        latestLocation.verticalAccuracy)
    print(latitude)
    print("wooe3reds")
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: NSError) {
    print("error")
}

}
```

Thanks!

**UPDATE:**
Here is how I initialize it:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class ZmanimViewController: YidController
{
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    let controller = ZmanimController()

}
}
```

Comment: How are you instantiating this object? Are you keeping a strong reference to it?

Comment: @Paulw11 In a UIViewController: "let controller = ZmanimController()"

Comment: Is that in a function or as a object property?  Please update your question to show the context of that line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are allocating the `ZmanimController` instance as a local variable inside `viewDidLoad` it will be released as soon as that function returns.

You should allocate the object instance as an object property of your `YidController`, that way it will have the same lifetime as that object instance.

Answer (score -1):

Are you adding `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` to your info.plist? Also, I notice you are calling `locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()` twice, you could remove one to be safe.

You are instantiating the view with

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    let controller = ZmanimController()

}
```

Are you presenting it in the same block? If not, the view will not stay in memory. You should either declare as a property (at the top of your file) or present the view.

Comment: Yes. The strange thing is that I'm using core location in another part of my app, and it's working fine there. I don't know why it's not working here.